# UICollectionView not displaying images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

I am creating an array of images selected from the phones camera roll.  They are being stored but for some reason I can't get them to display in my collectionView.

in my CollectionViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.photoCollectionView registerClass:[PhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell"];

    self.assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [super viewDidLoad];



- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.assets.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    cell.asset = asset;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;

}
```

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];

[tmpAssets addObject:image];

self.assets = tmpAssets;

self.testImage.image = [self.assets objectAtIndex:0];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

[self.photoCollectionView reloadData];
```

}

in my PhotoCell.h class

```
@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) ALAsset *asset;

@end
```

in my PhotoCell.m class

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"

@interface PhotoCell ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;

@end

@implementation PhotoCell

- (void) setAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    _asset = asset;
    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
}
@end
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever put anything into your assets mutable array. Are you doing that somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my question.  Missed it off

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Does it crash? Post the error message if you're getting one.

Comment: Yes it crashes 2015-01-20 21:18:40.150 BabyDiary[2382:115642] -[UIImage thumbnail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe75d09a340
2015-01-20 21:18:40.164 BabyDiary[2382:115642] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage thumbnail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe75d09a340'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're calling thumbnail on a UIImage which doesn't have that method. It would appear that your asset is a UIImage, not an ALAsset.